# Count Diophantine solutions to $x^2+xy+y^2≤r^2$. How to obtain geometric series? Eisenstein integer- Triangular lattice

Tags: geometry, number-theory

I am trying to understand how it is obtained the right part:
$$ \sum_{x,y \in Z } q^{x^2 + xy + y^2} = 1 + 6 \sum_{k\geq 0} (\frac{q^{3k+1}}{1 - q^{3k+1} } - \frac{q^{3k+2}}{1 - q^{3k+2} }).$$ I want to understand the math behind the right part.
I found this expression in different articles but without an easy explanation. This is one  [https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~slc/wpapers/s42hirsch.pdf](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Eslc/wpapers/s42hirsch.pdf). Why is $ 3k+1$ and $3k+2$?. And what it means geometrically? In this case it is a triangular lattice but which points represents $ 3k+1$ and  and which points represents $3k+2$?
If someone can explain to me like for dummies. This is useful for finding triangular lattice points [Oeis A308685](https://oeis.org/A308685%7D):
$$N(r) = 1 + 6 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lfloor \frac{r^2}{3k+1}\rfloor - \lfloor \frac{r^2}{3k+2}\rfloor. $$
I found that $N(r)$ expression is coming from geometric series:
$$\frac{x}{1-x} = x + x^2 + x^3+ \dots$$
but I don't get it. Any help?

Comment: The power series is the generating function of [OEIS sequence A004016](https://oeis.org/A004016) which has many references, in particular to [OEIS sequence A002324](https://oeis.org/A002324) which has an interpretation in terms of the difference of the number of divisors of the form 3k+1 and the form 3k+2.

Comment: I looked at every references and I still don't get it